# Rhino on Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, rhino

I have a JavaScript file which has a few variables and some data that I need to use in my Android app. I am new to JavaScript and I understand that the Rhino engine provides methods to use JavaScript in my code. The problem is that I am not able to understand how. Can someone point me to a good tutorial or give a small example of how it must be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to this link for rhino-1.7R3 api doc.

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R3/rhino-1.7R3-javadoc.jar!/index.html

for Rhino Tutorial go to this links

http://divineprogrammer.blogspot.in/2009/11/javascript-rhino-on-android.html

**EDIT On 1st July 2016**

Above content at links have been removed by their admin.

Please follow this link for rhino tutorial

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial

Comment: For rhino tutorial,You may check this also 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial

Comment: Please consider updating your answer - the blog in question does not exist anymore.  Neither does jarvana.com